# How can i get the manufacture name of a device from an IP address

Tags: c#, device, ping

I have a program that detects if a specific IP address is on the network. However, what I would like to do instead is scan the entire network for any devices made by a specific manufacturer.

I can work out how to scan ping the entire network that’s fine but where would I start if I wanted to get the manufacturer information from the IP address?

Comment: Are you confusing IP addresses with MAC addresses? The former doesn't give you any manufacturer information, while the latter could (though they can be spoofed also).

Comment: If the device is a PC, you can use WinRM/WMI. If it's not, something like SNMP would do. In all cases you need the device to actually cooperate, unless you want to do unreliable things like look up the MAC address and derive the manufacturer from that.

Comment: This doesn't really feel like a programming question at the moment; perhaps a more fleshed out version should be asked on Server Fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your program can scan by MAC address instead this would be a lot easier for you. [This website](https://macvendors.com/) allows you to look up device manufacturer by the MAC address, and the site even has an API so you can fully integrate it into your program. Assuming that all the devices you want to scan for are in the same network, you shouldn't have any problem finding their MAC addresses.

Also for further reading, please see [this post here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64281/how-to-get-mac-address-via-ip) for a similar question.

Comment: Device manufacturer being the network card manufacturer, not necessarily the overall device manufacturer, of course.

Comment: Yes, John is correct. I should have been more precise.

Comment: Ah ha, I see that would be why google didnt give me any clues about how to do it via IP.